# Exchange data.table columns with most prevalent value of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have data

```
test = data.table(
  a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), 
  b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), 
  c = rep(1, 6)
)
```

I wish to take the unique values of column *a*, store it in another data.table, and afterwards fill in the remaining columns with the most prevalent values of those remaining columns, such that my resulting data.table would be:

```
test2 = data.table(a = c(1,3,4,5,6), b = "a", c = 1)
```

Column be has equal amounts of "a" and "c", but it doesn't matter which is chosen in those cases.

Attempt so far:

```
test2 = unique(test, by = "a")
test2[, c("b", "c") := lapply(.SD, FUN = function(x){test2[, .N, by = x][order(-N)][1,1]}), .SDcols = c("b", "c")]
```

**EDIT**: I would preferrably like a generic solution that is compatible with a function where I specify the column to be "uniqued", and the rest of the columns are with the single most prevalent value. Hence my use of lapply and .SD =)

**EDIT2**: as @MichaelChirico points out, how do we keep the class. With the following data.table some of the solutions does not work, although solution of @chinsoon12 does work:

```
test = data.table(a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), 
                  b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), 
                  c = rep(1, 6),
                  d = as.Date("2019-01-01"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
dtmode <- function(x) x[which.max(rowid(x))]
test[, .(A=unique(A), B=dtmode(B), C=dtmode(C))]
```

data:

```
test = data.table(
    A = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), 
    B = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), 
    C = rep(1, 6)
)
```

Comment: ah, this is very elegant, thank you! I didn't know of rowid()

Answer (score 2):

Not a clean way to do this but it works.

```
test = data.frame(a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), c = rep(1, 6))

a = unique(test$a)
b = tail(names(sort(table(test$b))), 1)
c = tail(names(sort(table(test$c))), 1)

test2 = cbind(a,b,c)
```

Output is like this:

```
> test2
     a   b   c  
[1,] "1" "c" "1"
[2,] "3" "c" "1"
[3,] "4" "c" "1"
[4,] "5" "c" "1"
[5,] "6" "c" "1"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! This is unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I do not wish to hardcode anything =)

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Sorry, that was not very clear, I agree. I mean: 1) a solution where variable names are not explicitly written in code, like line 2, 3 and 4. 2) a solution that will work for more columns than I have stated in my example, i.e. I want a data.table solution with .SD + .SDcols

Answer (score 2):

@EmreKiratli is very close to what I would do:

```
test[ , c(
  list(a = unique(a)),
  lapply(.SD, function(x) as(tail(names(sort(table(x))), 1L), class(x)))
), .SDcols = !'a']
```

The `as(., class(x))` part is because `names` in R are always `character`, so we have to convert back to the original class of `x`.

You might like this better in `magrittr` form since it's many nested functions:

```
library(magrittr)
test[ , c(
  list(a = unique(a)),
  lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    table(x) %>% sort %>% names %>% tail(1L) %>% as(class(x))
  })
), .SDcols = !'a']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good point about the class. None of our codes actually work when we have a date column in data.table *test*. test = data.table(a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), 
                  b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), 
                  c = rep(1, 6),
                  d = as.Date("2019-01-01"))

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make an OK solution, but if somebody can do it more elegantly, for example not going through the step of storting a list in *refLevel* below, please let me know! I'm very interested in learning data.table properly!

```
#solution:
test = data.table(a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), c = rep(1, 6))
test2 = unique(test, by="a")
funPrev = function(x){unlist(as.data.table(x)[, .N, by=x][order(-N)][1,1], use.names = F)}
refLevel = lapply(test[, c("b", "c")], funPrev)
test2[, c("b", "c") := refLevel]
```

...and using a function (if anybody see any un-necessary step, please let me know):

```
genData = function(dt, var_unique, vars_prev){

  data = copy(dt)
  data = unique(data, by = var_unique)

  funPrev = function(x){unlist(as.data.table(x)[, .N, by=x][order(-N)][1,1], use.names = F)}

  refLevel = lapply(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = vars_prev], funPrev)
  data[, (vars_prev) := refLevel] 

  return(data)
}
test2 = genData(test, "a", c("b", "c"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variant which one might find less sophisticated, yet more readable. It's essentially chinsoon12's `rowid` approach generalized for any number of columns. Also the classes are kept.

```
test = data.table(a = c(1,1,3,4,5,6), 
                  b = c("a", "be", "a", "c", "d", "c"), 
                  c = rep(1, 6),
                  d = as.Date("2019-01-01"))
test2 = unique(test, by = "a")
for (col in setdiff(names(test2), "a")) test2[[col]] = test2[[col]][which.max(rowid(test2[[col]]))]
```